# Alternative ways to create .env file in github actions

Tags: github-actions, amazon-ecs, cicd

In order to deploy my code (hosted on Github) into an ECS instance, I have defined a .yml workflow that creates the .env file according to GH secrets; something like this

```
- name: env file creation
  uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1.3
  with:
    envkey_MYSQL_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_USERNAME }}
    envkey_MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_PASSWORD }}
    ... other env variables
    file_name: .env
    directory: './'
```

I would like to have different .env file for different environments (staging, production), but with the approach I am using now I should define new GH secrets for differents envs.

What are my alternatives insteade of using GH action SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1.3 in order to pass the .env file in my code (In the application, nodejs-express, I use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package to read the .env file)?

Comment: Instead of creating a .env file to (I assume) include in your docker image, why not just use environment variables in the ECS task definition?

Comment: Yea, I could also attach a .env hosted in a s3 instance, but how do I read these variables inside my nodejs-express app?

Comment: When your code does `proces.env.MYSQL_USERNAME` it will check for the environment variable by default. You have to do extra stuff with the `dotenv` library to add those values from the `.env` file into environment variables. With docker images it's easier, and more portable, to just set environment variables directly on the container instead of using `.env` files.